# Yii 1.1x logs out the user before session timeout

Tags: php, session, yii

I'm using Yii 1.1.13 and despite the session timeout is set to 1 day (`session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400` in *php.ini*) Yii logs out the user after ~24 mins. It doesn't even redirect to the login page, only when the user would navigate to another page.

I set these in the login function:

```
    $duration = Yii::app()->getSession()->getTimeout();
    Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
```

(the `Yii::app()->getSession()->getTimeout()` call gives back the right time, that is *86400*)

I also set the cookie lifetime to this value:

```
Yii::app()->request->cookies['PHPSESSID']->expire = Yii::app()->getSession()->getTimeout();
```

but the bug still appears.

Thank you in advance for your helping answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to set this in my *main.php*:

```
'session' => array(
    'timeout' => 86400,
    'cookieParams' => array(
            'lifetime' => 86400,
    ),
)
```

It keeps alive both the session and the cookie even if they are somehow given a lower value.